# Footer goes up when the keyboard is displayed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, footer, android-softkeyboard

I've been searching for the solution for this problem but I didn't find any that could solve my problem.

I'm using RelativeLayout as my main layout and my footer is RelativeLayout too, I found in the internet these configurations:

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"

It works for the footer stays fixed but my scroll does not work, that's my main problem, what can I do for solving it?

**My layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ttvp1"
                    style="@style/ttvPersonalizado"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/p1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ttvp2"
                    style="@style/ttvPersonalizadoDireito"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/p2" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtP1"
                    style="@style/edtPersonalizado"
                    android:maxLength="5"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_design"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal" >
                </EditText>

                 <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtP2"
                    style="@style/edtPersonalizado"
                    android:maxLength="5"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_design"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ttvpim"
                style="@style/ttvPersonalizado"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/pip3" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtPiP3"
                style="@style/edtPersonalizado"
                android:maxLength="5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_design"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ttvExame"
                    style="@style/ttvPersonalizado"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingRight="18dp"
                    android:text="@string/notaExame" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/chkExame"
                    style="@style/chkPersonalizado"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:text="@string/exame" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtExame"
                    style="@style/edtPersonalizado"
                    android:maxLength="5"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_design"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:width="125dp" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/chkPersonalizado"
                    style="@style/chkPersonalizado"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/tecnologo" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                style="@style/ttvPersonalizado"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/mediaFinal" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtMedia"
                style="@style/edtPersonalizado"
                android:maxLength="5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_design"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ttvStatus"
                style="@style/ttvPersonalizado"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnGerarMedia"
                    style="@style/btnMedio"
                    android:background="@drawable/shapebutton"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/gerarMedia"
                    android:src="@drawable/icone_calculadora"
                    android:text="@string/gerarMedia" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background_footer"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" />


</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**My activity configuration in AndroidManifest:**

```
<activity
            android:name="br.com.media_universidades.visao.MediaCalculoActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/umc" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"/>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add your layout to the question so we can see what you are working with.

Comment: Part your layout, and confirm that it has scrollview

Comment: Change `android:windowSoftInputMode` value to `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize`. Hope it help

Comment: Piotrek, with "stateVisible|adjustResize" I can use the scroll but my footer goes up, I need that my footer stays fixed and my scroll works.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which version on android you are using and how your layout is will have a different solution:

```
<activity
    android:name="br.com.media_universidades.visao.MediaCalculoActivity"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/umc" 
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

Edit: fixed the above code as the pervious answer I wrote was using this

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"/>
```

But sometime you have to force it by using the code in onCreate() method:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Here is a fix and here is the [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) on this.

> The setting must be one of the values listed in the following table,
>   or a combination of one "state..." value plus one "adjust..." value.
>   Setting multiple values in either group — multiple "state..." values,
>   for example — has undefined results. Individual values are separated
>   by a vertical bar (|). For example:

But I didnt read OP question correctly and hes scrollview isn't moving. This requires a OnGlobalLayoutListener()which is added to the scroll view.

```
final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.activityRoot);
activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {
    Rect r = new Rect();
    //r will be populated with the coordinates of your view that area still visible.
    activityRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

    int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);
    if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
        ... do something here
    }
 }
});
```

[Here are some awesome way to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android/4737265#4737265). The code above is from @Kachi.

Comment: S A, this solution only solve the scroll problem but my footer still goes up with android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize", is there any way to the scroll works and the footer not goes up?

Comment: @RafaelChinelatoDelNero have tried with just android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"> ? That worked for me!

Comment: S A, when I put only "adjustResize" my footer still goes up, I dont want this behavior.

Comment: @RafaelChinelatoDelNero ok added more to the above post.

Comment: Even using the code above, my scroll does not work. What if using another layout? LinearLayout does not stay in the bottom of the screen, it must exist a simple way to do it, it's just a footer.